# Viewcount with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, hitcounter

I have a form with a dropdown menu , that has different genres of movies , this is the code for that :

```
 <select name="genero"><?php 

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       if (!empty($_POST['genero']) && $row['nombre'] == $_POST['genero']) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["nombre"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}




 ?>
```

Then i have a isset that controls that a specific genre has been selected

```
    if (isset($_POST['genero'])) {


        $genero=$_POST['genero'];
        $sql = "UPDATE generos SET visitas=visitas+1 where nombre='$genero'";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                 $ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
                } else {
                echo "Error sumando visita: " . $conn->error;}
```

now here's the thing , when a user first enters said form i store their ip ( the way it's stored does not need to be super secure so that's why i do it like this)

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
```

that's why when the UPDATE query is successfully executed i store that ip again.
That update what does is serve has my count for views , so i can know how many clicks a specific genre has , but the way the code works now makes it useless since a user can click 50million times on one genre at it would count them.
What i'm trying to do is compare the fist ip to the second ip and if the ip is the same do a query that subtract 1 to that genre so only 1 is added 
this is what i've tried

```
     $contador=$contador+1;
    if (isset($_POST['genero'])) {

        $genero=$_POST['genero'];
        $sql = "UPDATE generos SET visitas=visitas+1 where nombre='$genero'";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                 $ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);

                } else {echo "Error sumando visita: " . $conn->error;}      

                if ($contador>1) {
                     if ($ip2==$ip){
                         $sql = "UPDATE generos SET visitas=visitas-1 where nombre='$genero'";
                         if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {}

                         }


                    }
```

then i tried something like this with isset , checking that the first update had been done already

```
    if (isset($ip2) and ($ip==$ip2)) {
                    $sql = "UPDATE generos SET visitas=visitas-1 where nombre='$genero'";
                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {}}
```

but what happened is that the number stays the same since it adds 1 and substracts 1

Comment: Okay, show us what you have tried in order to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code there, reading code in the comments it virtually impossible.

Comment: Tried that  , with a counter , when it is 1 so there's been an update already , then control the ip address , if it's the same then substract one so that it doesnt keep increasing

Answer (score 1):

Trying to keep track of the number of visitors by looking at their IP is not a good idea:

- There are too many IPs to keep track of them, e.g. for IP V6 there will be 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 different IPs
- The IP of a visitor may change over time. E.g. my IP changes with each new connect. The concrete IP is chosen by my ISP.

I suggest doing the following:
Instead of counting IPs it is much better to flag each vistor as beeing a visitor of a specific genre using PHP sessions. Sessions will be client specific, not IP specific which makes them much more reliable.

Just a code fragment to illustrate the idea:

```
session_start();
...
// form has been submitted && session value has not been set
if (isset($_POST['genero']) && !isset($_SESSION[$_POST['genero']]) ) {
  // We have a new visitor
  // 1. update DB
  // 2. Set cookie value
  $_SEESION[$_POST['genero']] = true;
}
```

I hope this gives you a new perspective on the problem.

Comment: yeah i see what you are saying , i would have to  find a way to use it with the already opened session ( that identifies said user in the system)